# Xdebug (on Vagrant) not working on VSCode

Tags: php, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vagrant, xdebug

I have a working bunch of Vagrant + Ubuntu. Everything works except Xdebug.

**Vagrant file:**

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000
```

**xdebug.ini:**

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.33.10
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/project.local/.xdebug/xdebug.log
```

**launch.json (on VSCode):**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/project.local": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "port": 9000,
            "log": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to start trace, I get the log entries:

```
Log opened at 2019-10-12 19:41:07
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 192.168.33.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/project.local/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.0.4-5ubuntu1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="16347" idekey="vagrant"><engine version="2.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2019-10-12 19:41:07
```

Breakpoints are not working, tracing is not starting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) *"config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9000, host: 9000"* -- Why/What for? It's Xdebug that connects to IDE (VSCode) and NOT other way around ...so why exposing 9000 port? RTM on how Xdebug works first. 2) Based on your Xdebug log .. it connects to a service that knows what Xdebug is .. and then just tells it to go away. Most likely Xdebug must be connecting to php-fpm (as it also uses TCP 9000 port by default). So far (for me at very least) it's misconfiguration on your end.

Comment: Possible solutions: 1) do not expose Xdebug port -- nothing should connect from outside. 2) Use different port for Xdebug (e.g. 9001).

Comment: Yep, I change port to 9001 in all setting and it helps. A bit strange. Perhaps port 9000 is busy with something else. Thank you.

Comment: Try to change this: "/var/www/project.local": "${workspaceFolder}" for this:"/var/www/project.local": "${workspaceRoot}", on launch.json. Besides, maybe this link helps you as helped me:  https://gist.github.com/sveggiani/10b6edd899412d6bdadd23c20607cf79